# Why not support images/.css folders for SpringBoot project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I created a spring boot project with the JSP front end. But .jsp files are working fine. CSS and Image folders are not supported for the project?
(attached file - 1.folder-structure.png)

**What would be the best possible options?**

```
/holidays/src/main/resources/application.properties

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

[image]

Comment: And what isn't working? Referencing this like `/static/css/your.css` should work without issues (unless you decided to add something like `@EnableWebMvc` which would disable parts of the auto configuration which handles this. Finally you really shouldn't be using JSP but something like Thymeleaf. JSP support with embedded containers is limited and error prone.